# IdentityServer4 with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have to implement OAuth for .NET Core and the decision is IdentityServer4. In fact, result should be an Authentication Endpoint also with login UI, reset password UI etc. However, OAuth must be fitted to existing database structure. So I cannot simply follow easiest 'Quickstart' manuals.

I am trying to understand concept of IdentityServer4 and I am confused about ASP.NET Core Identity and it's role in it. As far as I know, the ASP.NET Core Identity provides framework for user management including signin, signup, password reset etc, including database (with EntityFramework).

I have an existing SQL database which I have to use, there is no chance to any change. However, structure is similar to ASP.NET Core Identity so I assume it may be used (somehow). I found articles how to implement sort of 'custom users'

A/ directly to IdentityServer4, article [here](https://damienbod.com/2017/04/14/asp-net-core-identityserver4-resource-owner-password-flow-with-custom-userrepository/)

or

B/ to ASP.NET Core Identity, article [here](http://danderson.io/posts/using-your-own-database-schema-and-classes-with-asp-net-core-identity-and-entity-framework-core/)

Both ways are doable, back to original question - I would like to just get bit deeper to IdentityServer4 and find out how much it relies on ASP.NET Core Identity.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IdentityServer4 had 2 DbContexts that are a part of the framework which you will have to use if you're going to store these to the database. The ConfigurationDbConext for client and flow configuration. And the PersistentGrantDbContext for storing tokens and such. These 2 DbContexts are the only core part of IdentityServer4. These can also be stored in memory, but I wouldn't advise that. These 2 dbcontexts can be stored along side the existing database tables, or in another database if you want to.

User-management and such are not part of the IdentityServer framework, and you can use the implementation of your liking, like ASP.NET Core identity or something custom. In the article you mentioned, the magic happens within the `IProfileService` service,where users are retrieved and the `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` where credentials are validated. Use these custom implementations to retrieve and validate the users from your existing database.

Also, if you look at the quickstart example project, you'll see the UserStore is injected into each controller. Feel free to replace this one with your own user-repository if you need to. So to answer your question, IdentityServer4 doesn't rely on any user/role related storage framework, but you can attach however you want to.

For example: in my projects, User management, and authentication are 2 different microservices. Within the cluster, IdentityServer calls the user-service internally to get the user that is requested, but it isn't even part of the Auth microservice. The auth service just focusses on the OpenId connect implementation but knows basically nothing about users at all.

Comment: Thomas, thanks a lot! How about UI? Basically I need to have an Authentication endpoint (one of your two microservices) which provides also UI for login and maybe UI for password reset. This UI comes with ASP.NET Core Identity package or it has to be done manually anyway?

Comment: There is a Quickstart template available to get you up and running very fast. You can use this as a reference, or implement this right away in your project to get you up and running in no-time. The quickstart UI template provides UI for every scenario. 
Usually, I use this one and modify it from there. The UserStore and TestUser set that is references in the QuickStart UI template should be replaced with your own of course. If you want to use this with existing controllers and views, just use it as a reference for the logic.

https://deblokt.com/2019/09/01/01-identityserver4-quickstart/

Comment: Thanks man! So, as far as I understand, ASP.NET Identity is extra layer on top of IdentityServer4 (well, it depends on point of view). If I do not want to solve issues with password hashing etc, I may want to use ASP.NET Identity with custom IUserStore provider, which solves this for me. If I want to DIY password validation, hashing etc, I should avoid ASP.NET Identity at all and go directly with IdentityServer4 and its interfaces. Login UI is part of Quickstart, I may use it or create it completely on my own, it has nothing to do with IdentityServer4 and/or ASP.NET Identity

Comment: Well, it's a bit more nuanced than that, but I think if you tinker around with the quickstart-UI and try to hook it up with your ASP.NET Identity User tables you will get to understand the separation of concerns that Identity Server 4 embraces. But the bottom line is: user management, authorization, and login UI are 3 separate aspects in this matter, where Identity Server only handles the authorization part. The other 2 can be implementations which you prefer and the combination of these 3 make the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Has anybody successfully used PostgreSQL to store the ConfigurationDbConext and PersistentGrantDbContext context?

Comment: @MH, yes, i've used Postgress in numerous projects with Identity Server in combination with EF Core.